# running sudo commands with .bash_login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo, ubuntu-20.04

I want to run a few scripts when I start an interactive shell on my system. As I understand it, putting these commands in .bash_login should do the trick. Unfortunately, some of these commands require sudo. So how would I run such commands from .bash_login?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is sudo asking for password?
If yes, then for these particular commands that you want to run from your `.bash_login` file, use NOPASSWD option in `/etc/sudoers` file.

Assume you want to run for example the following command from `.bash_login`:

```
sudo rm /etc/someconfigfile
```

Then put the following line into `/etc/sudoers` (this file should be edited using `visudo` command):

```
myuser   ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:    /bin/rm /etc/someconfigfile
```

It means that user `myuser` is allowed to run command `/bin/rm /etc/someconfigfile` (you can use wildcards here) as `root` without asking for password.

For more detailed explanations, look `man sudoers`.